# Which about:config preference do I set in Firefox to make developer tools open when the browser launches?

Tags: debugging, firefox-developer-tools

I have been able to find preferences for Firebug to do this, but not having luck with Firefox Developer Tools.  Which about:config preferences can I toggle to make Firefox Developer Tools automatically visible and (preferably) docked when Firefox is first launched?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure whether you can do that right now in Firefox, but I filed an issue on this on the [Firefox DevTools Uservoice channel](https://ffdevtools.uservoice.com/forums/246087-firefox-developer-tools-ideas/suggestions/8842144-ability-to-launch-the-browser-with-devtools-alread), you could follow up with this there, too.